# ROS Launch file Issue

Tags: python, xml, ros, ubuntu-20.04, apriltags

I am implementing a simple roslaunch file but I am getting an exit code 2 status I have pasted the exact log below any idea what would cause this and how I can rectify it. It works perfectly when used as a node via rosrun.

```
PC@PC :~/catkin_ws$ roslaunch apriltag_ros apriltag.launch 
... logging to /home/pc/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/roslaunch-PC-20782.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt 
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://PC:38583/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
* /rosdistro: noetic
* /rosversion: 1.15.13

NODES
/
apriltag_ros (apriltag_ros/tagdetector.py)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [20790]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [20800]
started core service [/rosout] 
process[apriltag_ros-2]: started with pid [20803]
usage: tagdetector.py [-h] [-f FAMILIES] [-B N] [-t N] [-x SCALE] [-b SIGMA] [-0] [-1] [-2] [-c]
tagdetector.py: error: unrecognized arguments: __name:=apriltag_ros __log:=/home/pc/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2.log
[apriltag_ros-2] process has died [pid 20803, exit code 2, cmd /home/pc/catkin_ws/src/apriltag_ros/scripts/tagdetector.py __name:=apriltag_ros __log:=/home/pc/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2.log].
log file: /home/pc/.ros/log/c7672d6c-479d-11ec-bd02-c56b9aa24743/apriltag_ros-2*.log
```

The launch file code is as below

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>

<launch>
    <node name = "apriltag_ros" pkg = "apriltag_ros" type = "tagdetector.py"  output="screen" />
</launch>
```

Edit 1: I have added the function that I am using to publish to ROS where the ROS node is initialised and used.

The function I am using to publish the data is as below

```
# Import Libraries
from argparse import ArgumentParser
import sys
import cv2
import apriltagbase
import numpy as np
import math
import rospy
from apriltag_ros.msg import tag

def location_publisher():
    """
    ROS Publisher: Publishes X, Y and Yaw values
    """
    # rospy.myargv(argv=sys.argv)
    pub = rospy.Publisher('apriltag_pose', tag, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('apriltag_ros')
    msg = tag()
    msg.location.x = z # z in camera frame of reference is the distance from the tag i.e. x in general frame of reference
    msg.location.y = y
    msg.location.theta = yaw
    msg.status.data = status_tag
    msg.tagid.data = tag_id
    rospy.loginfo(msg)
    pub.publish(msg)

# Detect AprilTag
parser = ArgumentParser(description='Detect AprilTags from video stream.')
apriltagbase.add_arguments(parser)
options = parser.parse_args()

detector = apriltagbase.Detector(options, searchpath=apriltagbase._get_dll_path())

while(video.isOpened()):

    check,frame = video.read()
    
    if not check:
        break

    # overlay box on AprilTag format of detect_tags can be viewd in apriltag.py line 590.
    result,overlay = apriltagbase.detect_tags(frame, 
                                        detector,
                                        camera_params=(565.348501, 565.653872, 326.910261, 226.544390),
                                        tag_size=0.1688,
                                        vizualization=3,
                                        verbose=3,
                                        annotation=True
                                        )
    cv2.imshow('April Tag', overlay)
```

Edit 2: Removed Full code only open source code is now shown

Link to the same question on the ROS Forum: https://answers.ros.org/question/391124/roslaunch-exit-code-2-error/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output

> usage: tagdetector.py [-h] [-f FAMILIES] [-B N] [-t N] [-x SCALE] [-b SIGMA] [-0] [-1] [-2] [-c]

shows, that *tagdetector.py* is a script which needs to be called with some specific parameters.
First of all you should make sure, if the script is a rosnode to ensure launching it via roslaunch like this is correct.
Secondly, have a look at [the launch documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node) which shows how to add arguments to the node.

So you need to add some of the mentioned parameters to your launchfile by adding

```
args="-h"
```

to the node launch entry.

**Update**

The script you've added uses parses arguments defined in `apriltagbase`.

```
apriltagbase.add_arguments(parser)
options = parser.parse_args()
```

[argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) fails for all arguments which are not added here. So you need to replace it by

```
options, unknown = parser.parse_known_args()
```

to prevent failing due to arguments added automatically by roslaunch.

Comment: Note that if this is really a ros node all of those should be ros params.

Comment: When using rosrun I can see my node by using rosnode list thereby confirming that this indeed is the node. Coming to the arguments part my script does not need any arguments since all I am doing is publishing values for other nodes to subscribe (just like the basic talker node in the tutorial examples for ROS). As you can see in the documentation arguments are optional.

Comment: Please provide the code of tagdetector.py

Comment: @fruchtzwerg I have added the code in edit 1 in the question,

Comment: @NOVA1323 According to the error those arguments do not appear to be optional. No one can say exactly without the full code, though. As well, if you're calling that function multiple times you should *not* be creating the publisher or calling `init_node()` there.

Comment: Sorry @NOVA1323 this is not the full code. Itsnot possible to help you if you can't provide the full sources.

Comment: Made the necessary changes pleas have a look

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg for some reason I was notified by stack. Your Solution has solved my issue. Marking it solved.